# How can I use Cloudflare Key to setup HTTPS for create react app project?

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I use Cloudflare to generate cert and key with domain name (eg. *.domain.name), then I put the key files to my local machine and run `npm start` with .env config

```
HOST=localhost.domain.name
SSL_CRT_FILE=.cert/cert.pem
SSL_KEY_FILE=.cert/key.pem
```

but I got insecure warning why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, cloudflare doesn’t support localhost actually